# Calling a remove() on every element to empty an ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to write code that removes all movies from an `ArrayList`, blanking it so I can stuff more movies into it later.

I'll start with the code:

```
 for(int index = 0; index < movies.size(); index++){
            removeMovie(movies, movies.get(index));
            }
```

Everytime the loop runs, it will increment `index` and `movies.size()` should decrease. I need to keep `movies.size()` consistent while still representing the original `ArrayList` size. So, I want it to be like "index < ArrayListsOriginalSizeHereEvenThoughMyForLoopIsDecreasingItsSizeByRemovingMovies"

---

Here's something I tried just now:

```
int tempMovieSize = movies.size();
        for(int index = 0; index < tempMovieSize; index++){
            removeMovie(movies, movies.get(index));
            tempMovieSize += 1;
            }
```

This doesn't work though because I am getting an outofbounds exception. It should maintain the size of `tempMovieSize`. (It goes down by one because a movie object is removed, and is incremented by one, canceling it out and keeping it at the original value (in this case 8).)

Comment: No, you don't.  Either run the loop until `movies.size()` is `0`, always removing the first element, or better yet, use a `Iterator` and it's `remove` functionality

Comment: You're over-complicating it. It doesn't calculate `tempMovieSize` every time it goes around the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int size = movies.size();

int index=0;
while(index<size)
{
    removeMovie(movies, movies.get(index));

    index++;
}
```

also, you can use the ArrayList.remove(index) method to remove elements one by one

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_remove.htm

```
int size= movies.size();

int index=0;

    while(index<size)
    {
        movies.remove(index);

        index++;
    }
```

by the way, if you just want to remove all the elements from your list you can use

```
movies.clear();
```

or

```
movies.removeAll();
```

also, here is a fantastic explanation of how the clear() and removeAll() methods are different. Since you are a beginner, i think this will really help you in understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing the loop index at the end of each loop iteration.  But this is wrong because if you have just removed an element, you'll end up skipping the following element.

To fix this, you should not increment the loop index within an iteration in which you have just removed an element.

**Edit:**

Since you simply want to remove all movies:

```
movies.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a while loop with all your movies in it.  Then say something like

```
while (myMovieCollect.notEmpty()){
     removeMovie(myMovieCollect, myMovieCollect.get(0));
}
```

Of course this is psudeoCode but you get the idea.

Comment: Replace `index` with `0` (if I'm not mistaken). Every time an element is removed, the next element moves takes its position

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Suppose that `movies` is a list of size 2.  With your original code, you would first remove `movies.get(0)`, leaving a list of size 1.  The second time through, `index` is 1, and `movies.size()` is also 1, so the other movie won't get removed.

Your second attempt is even more problematic.  Each time through the loop, `index` increases by 1, and `tempMovieSize` also increases by 1.  Therefore, it's an infinite loop.

### Remedy

As others have mentioned, `movies.clear()` is the simplest way to empty the `movies` list.

If you actually need to call `removeMovie(…)` on every item in the list, and you have flexibility to choose the order in which you do so, then I suggest that you iterate backwards from the end:

```
for (int index = movies.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    removeMovie(movies, i);
}
```

One advantage is that you only need to call `movies.size()` once.  Another is that you are always removing the last element of the list.  Removing the first element of an `ArrayList` would be inefficient, since all of the subsequent elements would need to be copied over to fill the void.

Note that I've changed `removeMovie(…)` to take an index, so that it can do `movies.remove(index)` rather than `movies.remove(object)`.  The latter would necessitate searching through the list to locate the object to be removed, which would be involve traversing the list to the end again.